# Simplify a logic expression - Where have I gone wrong?

Tags: digital-logic

I am trying to simplify a logic expression but I think I simplified it too much. The expression is as follows:

$$\overline{\overline{(A \cdot B)} \cdot C \cdot (\overline{A}+\overline{(B+C)})}$$

This is what I got after I did the simplification:
But Logic Friday says that the answer should be:

$$A \cdot B+A \cdot C+\overline{C}$$

Which one is correct? Am I allowed to do the manipulations I did in this case?

Comment: I'd suggest filling two karnaugh tables to confirm that the two are equivalent (truth tables would work for that, Karnaugh tables would help fix the potential issue)

Comment: @user2357111317192329 I think this is an homework. You reach a better answer than what they (who assigned you the homework) expected to reach.
So, great job! (Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: @user2357111317192329: funny that you minimized the function better than *Logic Fridays*.

Comment: @CommuSoft thanks to Vladimir Cravero, he taught me this method of simplification!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both answers are correct.

Let:
$$
f_1(A,B,C) = AB+AC+\overline{C}\\
f_2(A,B,C) = A+\overline{C}
$$
Let's build the thruth table:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
A & B & C & f_1 & f_2 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

As you can see the two functions correspond.

Please note that this tabular method of proving that two functions are the same is perfectly valid and is called [Proof by exhaustion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_exhaustion).

Comment: You're welcome of course. Each question gives you a new weapon to defeat logic expressions, go for it!

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [De Morgan's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws#Engineering) twice. Using it once we get

$$A \cdot B + \overline{C} + \overline{(\overline{A} + \overline{(B+C)})}$$

Using it on the final term then gives us

$$A \cdot B + \overline{C} + A \cdot (B+C)$$

which simplifies to the expression given

$$A \cdot B + A \cdot C + \overline{C}$$

Comment: The question is about the possible further simplification.

Comment: Can't you simplify that last expression you got further like I did?